# How can I dynamically move a button on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’ve gone through the 1st 5,625 questions in the HTML section of the Stack Overflow website & I didn’t find any questions that seem to match my particular problem.

I have a button that I’ve placed on a web page using absolute positioning. I need to dynamically move that button to another location. So for example let’s ay the initial x & y co-ordinates of the button are 8 & 16 and in this instance I need to move it to say a position with x & y co-ordinates of 64 & 128.

I can find the position of the button by doing this :

```
the_Old_Button_X_Offset = document.getElementById 
(theButtonID).offsetParent.offsetLeft;

the_Old_Button_Y_Offset = document.getElementById
 (theButtonID).offsetParent.offsetTop ;
```

This will give me the x & y co-ordinates of 8 & 16. But when I try to reset the x& y co-ordinates of the button by doing this :

```
document.getElementById (theButtonID).offsetParent.offsetLeft = 64;
document.getElementById (theButtonID).offsetParent.offsetTop  = 128;
```

The values for “offsetParent.offsetLeft” & “offsetParent.offsetLeft” are still 8 & 16 & NOT 64 & 128. So obviously, I’m both doing something wrong & I’m not understanding something I should understand.

So what am I doing wrong? What is it that I’m missing? And Most importantly, how do I dynamically move a button from 1 location on a web page to another.

Thank for all your help & suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the new location to a class:

```
.class {top:100; left:100;}
```

and then add that class dynamically through javascript:

```
elem.className = "class";
```

or you can directly set the inline style attribute of top/left (or bottom/right, or top/right, or bottom/left)

```
elem.setAttribute('style', 'top:100px;left:150px;');
```

or you can use *elem.style*, whichever you prefer.

**elem** *is the absolute positioned element*

Comment: The block of text :

with(document.getElementById(theButtonID).style) {
    left = "64px";
    top = "128px";
}

Will rest the values of …style.left & …style.top to “64px” & “128px” respectively.

Unfortunately … It does NOT move the button.

Am I missing something here ?

Do I have to somehow force the HTML page to redraw itself ?

And, if so how do I do that ?

Comment: You definitely should not use the with statement in javascript, use of the with statement can be very hard to debug...  use JSLint.com to submit your code and follow the suggestions it gives you even if it hurts your feelings

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you set the initial position with this CSS:

```
#theButtonID {
    left:8px;
    top:16px;
}
```

Well, all you have to do is set:

```
with(document.getElementById(theButtonID).style) {
    left = "64px";
    top = "128px";
}
```

Note that if you want a smooth movement, add this CSS to the button:

```
transition:top 1s ease, left 1s ease;
-webkit-transition:top 1s ease, left 1s ease;
```

Comment: The block of text : with(document.getElementById(theButtonID).style) { left = "64px"; top = "128px"; } Will rest the values of …style.left & …style.top to “64px” & “128px” respectively. Unfortunately … It does NOT move the button. Am I missing something here ? Do I have to somehow force the HTML page to redraw itself ? And, if so how do I do that ?

Comment: Did you try adding the `transition` lines? That should have the element move smoothly.